# How to get a selected text from an active window in Ubuntu with Python?

Tags: python, ubuntu

I want to get a selected text from an active window into a variable with Python in Ubuntu. I tried to do it like this:

```
text = os.popen("xsel -o").read()
```

But it doesn't work properly. If I select a text with my mouse, everything works fine. But I got a problem if I select a text by the keyboard (for example, using `Shift + Home` or `Shift + arrows`). Is there a way to fix this problem?

Comment: Not sure about the answer, but your snippet works for me with keyboard selections on arch linux.

Comment: Did you look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1007185/how-to-retrieve-the-selected-text-from-the-active-window and http://askubuntu.com/questions/168887/how-can-i-add-cut-copy-paste-functionality-to-my-application?